# twitter bootstrap get an error on less compile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, codekit

i'm would like to use twitter bootstrap but assigning bootstrap classes at my own class
i get a compile error

for example

```
.myRow { .row-fluid; }
.myRowSpan { .row-fluid .span4; }
```

i'm using codekit compiler for less, and i import bootstrap at the top

```
@import "./bootstrap.less";
@import "./responsive.less";
```

now on myRow it is ok, but on myRowSpan i get an error

**NameError: .row-fluid.span4 is undefined in my.css**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
@import "./bootstrap.less";
@import "./responsive.less";
.myRow { .row-fluid; }
.myRowSpan { #grid .fluid .span(4); }
```

Comment: it works but can't understand why, in bootstrap.css (compiled from bootstrap.less) i can find: .row-fluid .span4{width:31.914893617021278%;*width:31.861702127659576%;}

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703684/extending-twitters-bootstrap-2-x-default-grid-span-classes-with-less-mixins/16713338#16713338 the spans are build with a function `span(@columns)`. This function is called a Parametric Mixin, see: http://lesscss.org/#-mixins